# Probability of Winning by 2 with the Law of Total Probability

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability

Problem:

Alice and Bob are playing a game together.  They play a series of rounds until one of them wins two more rounds than the other.  Alice wins a round with probability $p$.  What is the probability that Bob wins the overall series?

---

I attempted this problem and got it wrong, but I would like a second opinion in interpreting the solution so that I can learn from this experience.  As the title implies, the probability of Bob winning the entire series can be found using the Law of Total Probability.  I need some verification that I'm interpreting the constituent probabilities correctly.

If we let $C$ be the probability of winning the series overall, and each $B_i$ be the probability of Bob winning each round for matches $i = 0, 1, 2$, then we have the following:

$P(C) = P(C|B_2)P(B_2) + P(C|B_1)P(B_1) + P(C|B_0)P(B_0)$

In principle, this makes sense, however the next step establishes the following:

$P(B_2) = q^2$

$P(B_1) = 2pq$

$P(B_0) = p^2$

$P(C|B_2) = 1$

$P(C|B_1) = P(C)$

$P(C|B_0) = 0$

The first probability, $P(B_2)$ seems pretty straightforward, it's the probability of two consecutive wins, where $q = 1 - p$.

I'm uncertain about the second, $P(B_1) = 2pq$.  I think this represents the situations where Bob wins-Alice wins or Alice Wins-Bob Wins, which would be $pq + qp = 2pq$.  Does that seem correct?

I'm also shaky on the third one, $P(B_0) = p^2$.  I think this represents the situation in which Bob wins zero games, meaning Alice has one two (consecutive?) games to put her two over Bob for the win, hence the $p^2$.

For $P(C|B_2) = 1$, this must be the probability that Bob wins the overall series given he's already won two matches to put him over Alice, so this can only be 1 because of the "pre-condition".

But $P(C|B_1) = P(C)$ is a bit confusing for me.  I think this represents the situation in which a couple games have been played, but the players have ended up tied, so it "resets", and its existence is meant to represent the recursive nature of the game, which keeps going until one of the two players wins two more over the other.  Does that sound correct?

And the last one must be the probability that Bob wins the overall series given he won zero games, which of course makes that 0.

Put this all together and solve for $P(C)$ gives us $\frac{q^2}{1-2qp}$

Comment: For what it's worth, I worked out the solution before reading yours and got exactly the same answer. I can't find anything wrong with what you've written. What is the correct answer supposed to be if not $q^2 / (1 - 2qp)$?

Comment: That's reassuring.  Just to clarify, I was never in doubt of the answer, just my understanding of the solution.

Comment: I understand the final answer and most of the solution process but the definition for $B_i$ does not make sense to me. It includes "for matches $i=0, \dots, 1$", but then $B_2$ is used. I want to interpret $B_i$ to mean the probability that Bob wins $i$ matches out of $2$ consecutive matches. Is the definition of $B_i$ taken from a solution given to you?

Comment: Yes, but looking back on it, it looks like I goofed slightly when transcribing it here.  Strictly, its worded as "Let $B_i$ represent the event that Bob wins $i$ matches for $i = 0, 1, 2$.

Comment: Going to fix that in the original post, so thanks for bringing that up.

Answer (score 3):

It all checks out, except for how you describe the events.

---

I interpret $B_i$ as the event that **Bob wins $i$ among the first $2$ consecutive rounds**, for $i\in\{0,1,2\}$.

$B_0$ is the event that Bob wins *none of the first two rounds*, therefore certainly loses the game (Alice won).   Thusly, $\mathsf P(B_0)= p^2$ , and $\mathsf P(C\mid B_0)=0$ .

Likewise, $B_2$ is the event that Bob wins *two of the first two rounds*, therefore certainly wins the game.   Thusly, $\mathsf P(B_2)= (1-p)^2$ , and $\mathsf P(C\mid B_2)=1$ .

Finally, $B_1$ is the event that Bob wins *exactly one among the first rounds*, so $\mathsf P(B_1)= 2p(1-p)$ , because to do so, he must win either the first or second and Alice the other.    For a reality check, recall the Binomial Expansion Theorem: $$\mathsf P(B_0\cup B_1\cup B_2) {= p^2+2p(1-p)+(1-p)^2 \\=(p+(1-p))^2\\=1}$$

Now, should $B_1$ occur, both Bob and Alice shall have *won the same amount of rounds* and then begin the third round in the same state as they began the game.   So  $\mathsf P(C\mid B_1)=\mathsf P(C)$.

The rest is just LoTP and algebra.  $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(C)&=\mathsf P(B_0)\mathsf P(C\mid B_0)+\mathsf P(B_1)\mathsf P(C\mid B_1)+\mathsf P(B_2)\mathsf P(C\mid B_2)\\ &=p^2\cdotp 0+2p(1-p)\cdot \mathsf P(C)+(1-p)^2\cdotp1\\(1-2p(1-p))\mathsf P(C)&=(1-p)^2\\\therefore\qquad\mathsf P(C)&=\dfrac{(1-p)^2}{1-2p(1-p)}\\&=\dfrac{(1-p)^2}{p^2+(1-p)^2}\end{align}$$

---

Alternatively, consider this: **The game shall be won the first ocassion where an even number of rounds are played *and* the same player won the last two of these.**   Then the probability that Bob will be that player is:$$\dfrac{\mathsf P(B_2)}{\mathsf P(B_0)+\mathsf P(B_2)}=\dfrac{(1-p)^2}{p^2+(1-p)^2}$$

Comment: Three points: (i) doesn't P(C ∣ B1) depend on the order of outcomes within B1? In case of AB Bob will win with q and in case of BA only with q^2. (ii) Your formula does not agree with the above solution. (iii) Bob can win on even or odd number of rounds, no ?

Comment: The win condition is to "win two more rounds than the other player," not just two consecutive rounds.

Answer (score 0):

Why is the following solution using the geometric series incorrect ?
The only way Bob can win is one of the following:
$BB \cup ABB \cup BABB \cup ABABB \cup \ldots = (\_ \cup A \cup BA \cup ABA \cup \ldots )BB$
We can split this into the even and odd terms:
$$(\_ \cup BA \cup BABA \cup \ldots )BB + ( A \cup ABA \cup ABABA \cup \ldots )BB = \left(\bigcup_{k=0}{(BA)^k} \cup A\bigcup_{k=0}{(BA)^k} \right) BB$$
The probabilities of these events are just
$$
(1+p) \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{(qp)^k} \cdot q^2 = (1+p) \frac{1}{1-qp} \cdot q^2
$$
which is somewhat different from the correct solution:
[image: Comparing the two solutions]

Comment: The win condition is to "win two more rounds than the other player," not just two consecutive rounds.

Comment: $\rm ABB$ is Bob winning *one* more round than Alice.   @MarkusLoecher

Comment: Thanks a lot, that clarifies it! I indeed did not read the question carefully enough.